# Can't open sublime in Bash on Ubuntu on WIndows

Tags: windows, bash, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to be able to open the sublime text editor from the command line from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, but each time I attempt to run the command 'subl' I get hit with

```
    -bash: C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory
```

This is definitely the right directory, but I have no clue as to why this isn't working.  Any tips?

Comment: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?  So you have Sublime Text (great editor IMHO!) installed on Windows.  Where is that Ubuntu box?  You cannot run a Windows application inside Ubuntu (well directly anyway).  For Sublime, just download the linux version and install it in your Ubuntu.  Or clarify your question.

Comment: Conceptually that's the right directory, but it's the wrong path. In the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), the system volume is mounted at "/mnt/c", so the path should be `"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"`. Remember the quotes, because the path has spaces in it.

Comment: Okay so at this point in my .bashrc file I've added the following line

`alias subl = "/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"`

and now it tells me "No command 'subl' found', did you mean:" and then it lists some other options.  Not sure what isn't working with my alias. @eryksun

Comment: There shouldn't be spaces between the alias name and the path, plus the path should also be placed in single quotes in order to pass the double quotes literally, e.g. `alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run notepad as administrator.
2. Copy & paste this two line of code below:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash 
    "$(dirname "$0")/subl.exe" "$@"
   ```
3. Save it as subl.txt inside C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3
4. Open the folder 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3'
5. Finally right click and rename this file to subl. That means remove the .txt extension from that file.

Now, you are ready to use subl command on gitbash or wsl linux terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> There shouldn't be spaces between the alias name and the path, plus
> the path should also be placed in single quotes in order to pass the
> double quotes literally, e.g. alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program
> Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe"'. –  Eryk Sun  Feb 15, 2018 at
> 5:40

In my case, the following worked well.(sublime_text_build_4169_x64_setup.exe)

```
alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text/subl.exe"'
```